# Adding new data to API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, response

How can I add this arrayOfObjects to the data that is coming from the api response ?

I tried this pattern but didn't work for me

```
 const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  useEffect(() => {       
    const arrayOfObjects = [
       {num:1},
       {num:2},
       {num:3},
       {num:4},
       {num:5},
       {num:6},
       {num:7},
       {num:8},
       {num:9},
       {num:10},
    ];

    axios(url).then((res) => {
      const newData = res.data.map((item) => (item.arrayOfObjects.map(innerItem => innerItem) = num));
      console.log(newData);
    });
  }, []);
```

for example the result should look like this in the response data although "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" has 10 objects

```
[
     { 
       name: "Leanne Graham"
       num: 1
       etc. 
     },
     { 
       name: "Ervin Howell"
       num: 2
       etc. 
    },
    { name: "Clementine Bauch"
      num: 3
      etc. 
    }
etc.
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add property num for every object in the API data array.
This should do it:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const arrayOfObjects = [
      { num: 1 },
      { num: 2 },
      { num: 3 },
      { num: 4 },
      { num: 5 },
      { num: 6 },
      { num: 7 },
      { num: 8 },
      { num: 9 },
      { num: 10 }
    ];

    axios(url).then((res) => {
      const newData = res.data.map((item, idx) => {
        return { ...item, ...arrayOfObjects[idx] };
      });
      console.log(newData);
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked as needed.
i have a question for you, how about if I have two properties in each object like {num:1, color: "red"}, and I only want num, based on your code I am getting all the properties, How about if I only want one property , only num and ignore color ?

Comment: I just want to point out that in the solution posted by @binginsin the `num` comes from the index of the item in the array, whereas in min it comes from the value of `id`. I'm not sure which you want as you didn't specify. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear to me. If what you are trying to do is to combine the data from the API call with the data from `arrayOfObjects` into a single array, and then map that into an array of objects with just the `name` and `num` properties, you could do something like this:

```
axios.get(url)
  .then((res) => {
    const dataFromApi = res.data
   
    // this creates a new array which combines the array from the API call with the array in your component's local state
    const additionalData = [...dataFromApi, ...arrayOfObjects]
    
    // this creates a new array from the combined array which only has `name` and `num`
    const newData = additionalData.map(datum => ({
      name: datum.name,
      num: datum.num
    }))
    console.log(newData)
  })
```

If you just want to add a `num` to the API response where `num` === `id` you can do this:

```
axios.get(url)
  .then(({ data }) => data.map(datum => ({
      ...datum,
      num: datum.id
    })))
```

Comment: I just want to add num to each object of the response, I want all the data from the response not just name, I only put name so I don't have write all the data.

I have 10 nums, each one go to each object on the users objects

Comment: Okay. Would the value of num be equal to the value of id?

Comment: no, forget about id, num just an example i am using here, but my data is different, how about if I want only num of an object has more than one property like {num:1,color:"red"}?